# Visual Studio 2019 does not open window with source file and does not position to line with error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

There are some compile errors in Errors List after CMake project compilation.

Visual Studio 2019 does not open window with source file and does not position to line with error through double click on them.

Also Intellisense not working correctly.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the Output tab and see if it gives you more or better information. In general I prefer the Output tab because it doesn't chop up the compiler messages to make the display look pretty..

Answer (score 0):

Clean build project and delete folder .vs of your solution.

You can check the following link to know more about how to fix intellisense issues in Visual Studio: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Aug/07/Fixing-Visual-Studio-Intellisense-Errors